# Is brown sugar better than white for diabetes?

Tags: diabetes, sugar

As we know that diabetic patient does not eat sugar(white sugar) because the blood sugar level is not controlled.So,can a diabetic patient use brown sugar in replacement of white sugar? can brown sugar not effect the blood sugar level of diabetic patient?

Comment: As *you know*: Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you are ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Brown sugar is just white sugar with molasses added.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Type 1 and Type 2 diabetic patients can eat sugar under specific conditions. 
White and brown sugar are pretty much identical (from a "diabetic" viewpoint) and they respectively have a **Glycemic Index of [(+-10)](https://academic.oup.com/ajcn/article-abstract/34/3/362/4692881) 68 and 64** according to the Linus Pauling Institute.
So as a summary, no. Brown sugar **affects** the Blood Sugar level of a Diabetic patient similarly to white sugar.